# Annoying behavior when switching keyboard language between RTL/LTR

Tags: microsoft-word, input-languages

When I use the keyboard to switch the keyboard language while editing an RTL document (Arabic), MS Word also switches the direction and alignment of the paragraph, which is very annoying.

**More detailed:**

When editing an RTL document like in Arabic, a user might wish to enter a word or segment in an LTR language like English. To do that the user switches the keyboard language, and this can be done either using the mouse on the language bar (say in Win10), or using a keyboard shortcut for the toggling languages. The user in this case just wants to switch the keyboard language to enter an interspersed segment in another language, and does not want to switch the direction/alignment of the paragraph. When using the mouse there's no problem, but when using the keyboard shortcut, MS Words takes the shortcut to also mean to switch the paragraph direction/alignment.

How can I stop the keyboard language toggle shortcut from switching paragraph direction/alignment in MS-Word? Or alternatively is it possible to define another shortcut that would only toggle the keyboard language without affecting MS-Word?